# A Simple Question about Passing the Limit: If $a_n \to a$ and $a_n > c$, under what condition we have $a > c?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Consider a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_n \to a \in \mathbb{R}$ and for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n > c$ for some constant $c>0$. I was wondering under what assumption that we can still say that $a_n > c$?

I know if $a_n \to a$ and $a_n \geq c$, then we have $a_n \geq c$. However, if I only have strict inequality; i.e., $a_n > c$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is there a result for me to pass the limit and still have $\lim_n a_n = a > c$? or the best we we can say is $a\geq c$?

Any comment/suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Best you can say is greater than or equal to. Take a sequence of positive numbers converging to 0 for example.

Comment: Consider the sequence $b_n=a_n-c$ to show limit is greater or greater than equal to $0$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran, Let $b_n = a_n - c >0$ then taking the limit I got $\lim_n b_n = a - c$. But, at this stage, I couldn't see how the limit is greater than or equal to 0. Can you help to explain a bit more?

Comment: If there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that for infinitely many $n$, $a_n-c>\varepsilon$, then the inequality is strict in the limit (and $a-c\ge\varepsilon$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $\lim_n a_n$ exists, you will have $\lim_n a_n > c$ *if and only if* there exists an index $N$ and a number $d > c$ with the property that $n \ge N \implies a_n \ge d$.

Comment: It is enough that $a_n\ge d$ for infinitely many $n$ (of course, this ends up implying your version).

Comment: @Umberto P., thanks, is this a well-known result that I can find in some standard analysis textbooks? I am interested in reading it.

Comment: @Fianra I don't think so. It is a fairly straightforward application of the definition of the limit.